Is it P Hacking to run a set of bivariate tests to better understand the variables available for Machine Learning
I'm working on my portfolio and I have several machine learning models.  I would like to run a set of bivariate comparisons to better understand the relationships of possible predictor.  In addition to running these tests I'm using cross validation to avoid a data leak.
I am specifically not using a threshold based on p values (instead I'm looking at standardized effect sizes).  I would like to know relationships between my pool of possible predictor variables before committing to an iterative exercise in model building.
I am considering additional data on top of the effect sizes such as scatter plots, comparative histograms (showing the distribution of variable where membership in one histogram is assigned by a binary or categorical variable), etc.
Is this p-hacking?  Does it matter that only a single pass (cross validated) of comparisons is being made?
